# How to write a function whose fixed point is the Y combinator?

Tags: haskell, lambda

I must find a function `G` which has a fixed point, and this fixed point must be the Y combinator.

Recall that `Y F = F(Y F)` for all `F`. I want a function `G` such that `G Y = Y`.

How to write such a function in in Haskell?

Comment: The actual Y-combinator (which is actually a bit more complicated than what you wrote!) isn't really well-typed [unless you introduce some extra recursion trickery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Type_for_the_Y_combinator). However, _a_ [fixpoint combinator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix) can be implemented much easier: `fix f = let x = f x in x`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes. But `fix f = let x = f x in x` has Y-combinator as fixed point?

Comment: I took the liberty of rewording the question to make it clear what it is being asked. I think I got what the actual question was about, also considering your comments, but if I was wrong please re-edit and clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let

```
g w = \f -> f (w f)
```

Then, if

```
y f = f (y f)
```

we have

```
g y
-- definition of g
= \f -> f (y f)
-- property of y
= \f -> y f
-- eta-conversion
= y
```

Hence, `y` is a fixed point of `g`.

More than that: the set of fixed points of `g` is precisely the set of fixed point combinators. This is because above we did not exploit the definition of `y`, but merely the fact that it is a fixed point combinator.

Note that `y` is also a fixed point of `id` (anything is a fixed point of `id`)
and of `const y` (as @DanielWagner writes in his answer).

Comment: This answer is probably more in the spirit of the question. Nice one!

Comment: We can nicely infer this definition of g: `y f = f (y f)` => `y = id <*> y` => `g = (id <*>) `=> `g = \w f -> f (w f)`. Then we can generate new `g`s in an obvious way: `g' = g . g`, `g'' = g . g . g`. Or we can define `y'`, isomorphic to `y`, in terms of `y` and `g`: `y' = y g` and then `g' = ($ g)`, `g'' = ($ ($ g))` and so on. I.e. `y g = y = g y`, which is cool.

Comment: Thx! This is very good! But you can help me solve equation? `Y=(FX=X)` I must find F.

Comment: @kvendingoldo I can't understand your question. In any case, open a new question and explain the problem as clear as you can.

Answer (score 6):

For all values `v`, the function `const v` has (unique, and therefore also least) fixed-point `v`.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel's answer is very good, but I'd like to add the other extreme. Everything is a fixed point of the identity function. Thus, take **G** to be

```
\x -> x
```

indeed:

```
GY = (\x -> x)Y = Y
```